# Android Studio project FATAL EXCEPTION VerifyError

Tags: android, exception, android-studio

I have a project in android studio which was working correctly and as expected on all devices with API higher than API 16 (JellyBean and higher) suddenly after adding a few more section to the application I can only run it on devices with API 22 installed on it (Lollipop), when I try to run it on a device that have Kitkat installed in it, I get the following FATAL EXCEPTION in the launcher activity:

```
Process: android.visitabudhabi.com.vad, PID: 2939
    java.lang.VerifyError: android/support/v4/view/ViewPager
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2002)
            at android.visitabudhabi.com.vad.Walkthrough.onCreate(Walkthrough.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5403)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

OnCreate method in my launcher class (Walkthrough) :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_walkthrough);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        MySQLiteHelper mySQLiteHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        mySQLiteHelper.db_delete();

        one= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.first);
        two= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.second);
        three= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.third);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            int pos;
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                  pos=position;
                if(position==0)
                {
                  one.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c7333f"));
                }
                else if(position==1)
                {

                       two.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c7333f"));

                }
                else if(position==2)
                {
                    three.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c7333f"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if (pos == 2 && state == 1) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Walkthrough.this,Settings.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Anyone got an idea on how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

This is my build.gradle:

```
    compile files('libs/pinit-sdk-1.0.jar')
    compile project(':bounceScroller')
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.2.1@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.6-2'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.3'
    compile 'com.github.pedrovgs:draggablepanel:1.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.2.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile project(':rangeseekbar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':blurry')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

And this is the ViewPager I am using in my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

Comment: rollback code to the state before *adding a few more section to the application* should help ... as we can easily read from the logcat error is in the layout not in your code ...

Comment: check if you need to import a different version of ViewPager, i mean use different support library

Comment: ofcourse I did but nothing happened, still not working on devices other than lollipop. @Selvin

Comment: @JerrySangma I tried to update my support library and repository but nothing changed.

Comment: layout is ok ... so .... you should check if one of the imported library is not using different support v4 library version

Comment: How can I check that? do I check it from the layout of other activites?